# Branches on tomato plants are curling under

Tags: vegetables

I have 12 Tomato plants, planted two to a pot in very large plastic pots with proper drainage holes.  I used good quality peat based potting mix and have not fed them at all.  The weather here has been off and on wet and hot and sunny.  I would say at least 2 days a week of rain.  I have never seen this before.  I had my plants in pots last year as well and they didn't look like this.  The stems are curling under and the leaves are limpish, but the plants are continuing to grow and produce flowers.

Comment: Judith, why haven't you 'fed' your tomatoes?  Better answer would be why have you not added balanced fertilizer?  Fertilizer is not pesticide.  Fertilizer never comes with soil au naturale.    Did you make your own soil using Peat Moss?  Did you sterilize it?  What is your watering regimen?  Did you use any 'compost' in that soil?  Nitrogen that is higher than the existing or added P and K will produce lots of leaves, no fruit.  Very relative thing.  Planting 2 plants per pot is...okay but why did you do this?  The two plants are in competition for chemistry to run their factories!